# gradle's new plugins dsl syntax

Tags: gradle

I'm currently learning gradle build tool, specifically the [new plugins DSL syntax](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block), in the documentation. In the link, the author mentioned

[image]

I understand that for every `build.gradle` file, gradle implicitly create an object of type `Project` for the programmers to use and every variable/methods declared in the `build.gradle` file is implicitly attached to the `Project` object, so I looked up the [Project class API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#project-java.lang.String-groovy.lang.Closure-) for a method called `plugins` that accept an closure as its first argument, but none exist.

I understand the newer plugins dsl syntax is intend to replace the traditional `apply()` method mechanism. But why I cant find the `plugins` method in the `Project` class's documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Project* interface inherits from *PluginAware* interface, and this is where 'plugins' feature is handled : see method specification https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginAware.html#getPlugins--

But in fact, the *plugins { }* syntax is not related to a property or methods from Project class: its a kind of *script block* which is handled by Gradle in a special way, like *buildScript* block. You will find details about that in the official documentation there: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.html

Note: I recommend that you to check the DSL documentation instead of the Javadoc (or in addition to the Javadoc): I think it provides better description of what you can use when writting build scripts, with examples. The 'plugins' property for example is documented there :
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:plugins

regards.