# Where does plugins block method comes from?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

**Intro**

After using maven, I've been learning gradle, it's a bit not-easy and challenging specially since IDE (like intellij that I'm using) cannot take me to source of declared properties and configurations all the time. I think this is the Gradle Groovy DSL disadvantage. So looking to the documentation along with help of IDE I came to my first question that I failed to find an answer for so far

**The Question**

Where does `plugins` method comes from ?

**So Far I Found**

As I see its definition pressing Ctrl in Intellij and holding the mouse over it to be

`org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec PluginDependenciesSpec plugins (groovy.lang.Closure configuration)`

so it's a method that takes `Closure` as parameter like in this code

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'example.group'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Now where is the declaration/definition of such method ? Source code documentation states the following

> In a build script, the `plugins {}` script block API is of
>   this type. That is, you can use this API in the body of the plugins
>   script block to declare plugins to be used for the script.

Does that mean that build script is run not only against `Project` class as an exposed/instance only but also there is instance of `PluginDependenciesSpec` ?

Comment: Project implements PluginAware https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html which exposes this.  It's not always a 1:1 mapping as Gradle build scripts are a DSL, so some extra work may be going on behind the scenes.  If you're using Gradle 5+ and want better ide support, you can use the kotlin DSL which has better intellij support due to its less dynamic nature.

Comment: So no clear documentation about where this method is ? That is the effect of groovy DSL right ?. About Kotlin, I am actually reading about it to use it instead of groovy for gradle, it seems more logical to waste time on it instead. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to know what gets called when this bit of the DSL is reached?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block

Comment: Yeah I understand that it configures instance of `PluginDependenciesSpec`, but I needed to know and confirm it's NOT on any API documentation as a definition with a signature rather the one that inside the IDE. Why ? because I am getting started with Gradle and need to know the references of such property/properties which I may be missed or it's simply work behind the scene with no mention on the documentation other than `The plugins DSL block configures an instance of PluginDependenciesSpec`

Comment: you might find more details in this already answered question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522218/6899896

Comment: That exactly did answer the question.